# attachment image show on vf page

Tags: attachment, standardcontroller

I have preview page and pass Id in url
its show break image not showing proper image
this is my class code

```
Public Class displayImageExtension {

    String recId;

    public displayImageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        recId = controller.getId();    
    }

    public String getFileId() {
        String fileId = '';
        List<Attachment> attachedFiles = [select Id from Attachment where parentId =:recId order By LastModifiedDate DESC limit 1];
        if( attachedFiles != null && attachedFiles.size() > 0 ) {
            fileId = attachedFiles[0].Id;
        }
        return fileId;    
    }
}
```

this is my page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="displayImageExtension">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,FileId" />
    </apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Comment: While moving your code out of the image and into text, I noticed a syntax error- `url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,FileId"` should be `url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,FileId)}"`. You may want to try resolving this issue.

Comment: i tried then its shows 
Invalid parameter for function URLFOR

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the `URLFOR` you are currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show any image preview on Visualforce page

Check this code

Page

```
<apex:page controller="ViewPdf" >
    <iframe height="250px" width="350px" src="data:{!att.ContentType};base64,{!blobData}" ></iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class ViewPdf {
    public Document att {
        get {
            if (att == null) {
                att = [SELECT Id,Body, ContentType, Name FROM Document Limit 1];
            }
            return att;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public String blobData {
        get {
            return EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(att.body);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Using this code you can show all text files, images and PDFs on VF page.
2. Type of the document will be determined dynamically.
3. Support for other documents depends on the browser.

Comment: my requirment is Without Iframe show image on vfpage

Comment: You can also use html image tag in place of iframe

Comment: use <img id="theImage" src="data:{!att.ContentType};base64,{!blobData}"/>